# Find methods that have custom attribute using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute:

```
public class MenuItemAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and a class with a few methods:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    [MenuItemAttribute]
    public void Shout()
    {
    }

    [MenuItemAttribute]
    public void Cry()
    {
    }

    public void RunLikeHell()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I get only the methods that are decorated with the custom attribute?

So far, I have this:

```
string assemblyName = fileInfo.FullName;
byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyName);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);

foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
     System.Attribute[] attributes = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type);

     foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
     {
         if (attribute is MenuItemAttribute)
         {
             //Get me the method info
             //MethodInfo[] methods = attribute.GetType().GetMethods();
         }
     }
}
```

What I need now is to get the method name, the return type, as well as the parameters it accepts.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong.
You are looping through every *type* that has the attribute, which will not find any types.

You need to loop through every method on every type and check whether it has your attribute.

For example:

```
var methods = assembly.GetTypes()
                      .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
                      .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MenuItemAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: am i doing it ass-about-front here? cause right now i look for all the attributes and i then try and get the associated method

Comment: I tried it with your classes; it works for me.  Are you searching the right assembly?

Comment: doh... changed some of the code to make it simple for stackoverflow readers... never changed it back...

thanx... yours is correct

Comment: @Tom: `GetCustomAttributes()` returns an array anyway, so `.Any()` won't help.

Comment: use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() for the currently executing assembly

Comment: "You need to loop through every method" is true, but then your example uses `GetMethods()` which doesn't return every method, it only returns public ones.

Answer (score 25):

```
Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> methods = assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
    .Where(y => y.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<MethodAttribute>().Any())
    .ToDictionary(z => z.Name);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var classType = new ClassNAME();
var methods = classType.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m=>m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0)
.ToArray();
```

Now you have all methods with this attribute `MyAttribute` in class `classNAME`. You can invoke it anywhere.

```
public class ClassNAME
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public void Method1(){}

    [MyAttribute]
    public void Method2(){}

    public void Method3(){}
}

class MyAttribute: Attribute { }
```