# How can I get all types with a custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm trying to get all types with the code below based on these topics:

- [Get Method Details using reflection and decorated attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467765/get-method-details-using-reflection-and-decorated-attribute)
- [Creating Custom Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx)

So I have this attribute:

```
public class DataLayerInterfaceAttribute   : System.Attribute
{
    public DataLayerInterfaceAttribute() { }
}
```

And I have this interface:

```
[DataLayerInterfaceAttribute]
interface IInterface
{
    void Method(string param);
}
```

Finally I want to get the interface type:

```
var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(DataLayerInterfaceAttribute))
            select type;
```

I already tested with this:

```
var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where type.GetCustomAttributes(type,true).Length > 0
            select type;
```

But the result for both is empty and I dont know why.

EDIT

I'm getting the assembly like this:

```
string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
byte[] assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyName);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure you are using appropriate `assembly`

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using the wrong Assembly reference.

Comment: Why didn't you just write `Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();`?  Either way, the currently executing assembly is probably not what you want.  Are all your interfaces going to be in the same assembly or do you know the list of assemblies that they will be located in?