# Extract test cases from visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

How to extract all classes with "TestClass" attribute and all its methods with "TestMethods" attributes into an external file like .txt or excel types without using TFS?

Comment: you mean by clicking some sort of menu item or by executing self written code?

Comment: I actually dont know. You can suggest what you know

Comment: I don't understand why down vote. It is a valid question, I want to extract all Test classes and its test methods. What's up with it?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where to even start. I did some googling but couldn't find anything.

You know where there's no effort? Judging someone by downvoting a question when it is valid and assuming the person asking didn't do any effort.

Comment: [*find all classes by attribute c#*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607178/how-enumerate-all-classes-with-custom-class-attribute), [*find all methods by attribute c#*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467765/get-method-details-using-reflection-and-decorated-attribute), [*write text to excel file c#*](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/read-write-excel.html). 3 search queries that gave me everything I need to know in 2 minutes.

Comment: extract test cases in visual studio 2013, export test explorer vs2013 certainly didn't give anything for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably tools but here is a simple implementation using reflection:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("xxx.dll");

var testClasses = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(c => c.GetCustomAttribute<TestClassAttribute>() != null);

foreach (var testClass in testClasses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found test class " + testClass.FullName);

    var testMethods = testClass.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<TestMethodAttribute>() != null);
    foreach (var testMethod in testMethods)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found test method " + testMethod.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this if I don't find any tool soon

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
public void list__all_unit_tests()
{
    string sDLL = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
    string sFilePath = string.Format("{0:s}\\{1:s}.DLL", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), sDLL);
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(sFilePath);

    var testClasses = assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute),false)!=null);

    foreach (var testClass in testClasses)
    {
        var testMethods = testClass.GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute),true).Length !=0);

        foreach (var testMethod in testMethods)
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format("class,{0:s}, method,{1:s} ", testClass.FullName , testMethod.Name));
        }
    }
}
```